# Explanation of $\left < \cdot \right > $ notation

Tags: notation, cryptography

I am trying to understand the [Boneh-Goh-Nissim Cryptosystem](http://theory.stanford.edu/~dfreeman/cs259c-f11/lectures/bgn) and am getting confused.

I have found $n=qr$ for $q$ and $r$ prime.

I have found a supersingular elliptic curve $E\backslash\mathbb{F}_p$ for $p$ prime with point $P\in E\left(\mathbb{F}_p\right)$ of order $n$

I am then supposed to let $\mathbb{G}=\left<P\right>$

Can someone explain the $\left < \cdot \right > $ notation in this context to me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subgroup generated by the point $P$.